# Find BlackScholes PDE $\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + rS\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}=rC$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

G'day, I have some basic knowledge about Ito Calculus and Brownian Motions. We assume that stock price S follows the GBM:

- **1)** $()=_t_t+_tS_t_t$

The value of the change in portfolio is given by:

- **2)** $dX_t = rX_tdt + \Delta_t(u - r)S_td_t + \Delta_t \sigma S_tdW_t$

Let **C** be a call option written on underlying value S.
The differential of **$C(t,S_t)$** is given by:

- **3)** $dC(s,S_t) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}(dS_t)^2$
- **4)** $= [\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + uS_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}]dt + \sigma S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dW_t $

to get eventually the result:

- **5)** $\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + rS\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}=rC$

I am very much wondering how we get from step **3)** to **4)** doing the derivation. When I was calculating stochastic equations, my method was to define f(x) = $X^3$, f'(x)= $3x^2$, f''(x) = 6x and then substitute them in Ito's lemma. Can someone use a similar approach?

**And with the icing on the cake: how do we eventually get to step 5).**

Any help or tips is very much appreciated!

Linked: [How to obtain $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \sigma}$ from Black-Scholes PDE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582444/how-to-obtain-frac-partial-c-partial-sigma-from-black-scholes-pde)

Answer (score 1):

You have a self-financing portfolio $X_t=B_t+\Delta_tS_t$ where $B_t$ is your risk-free rate bond.

You want $X_t+C(t,S_t)=0$, in other words, a perfect hedge.

You also have 
$$dX_t+dC(t,S_t)=0$$

By using the self-financing property of $X_t$
$$dX_t=dB_t+\Delta_tdS_t$$

Using Ito's lemma on $C$, we have 
$$dC(t,S_t) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}d<S_t,S_t>$$

with $d<S_t,S_t>=(\sigma_tS_t)^2dt$

Using the third equation, we have 
$$dB_t+\Delta_tdS_t+\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}(\sigma_tS_t)^2dt=0$$

To get rid of the source of randomness $dS_t$, a natural choice is $$\Delta_t=-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}$$

Therefore,
$$dB_t+\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt +   \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}(\sigma_tS_t)^2dt=0$$

The bond grows are the risk-free rate $r_t$, hence
$$dB_t=r_tB_tdt$$ 
Thus,
$$r_tB_tdt+\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt +   \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}(\sigma_tS_t)^2dt=0$$

Using the first two equations and the definition of $\Delta$, we have 
$$B_t=-C(t,S_t)-\Delta_tS_t=-(C(t,S_t)-\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}S_t)$$

Finally you have (removing the dt)

$$-r_tC(t,S_t)+\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}r_tS_t+\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} +   \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}(\sigma_tS_t)^2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain 4), you plug $_t=_t_t+_tS_t_t$ into

$$dC(t,S_t) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dS_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}(dS_t)^2$$

and use $(_t)^2 = (_tS_t_t)^2=\sigma_t^2S_t^2dt$ to get

$$dC(t,S_t) = \left[\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + uS_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}\right]dt + \sigma S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dW_t $$

To arrive at 5). You construct the hedged portfolio with $-\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}$ unit of stocks and apply the non-arbitrage argument that any hedged portfolio is equivalent to the risk-free portfolio that grows at risk-free rate $r$, i.e.

$$dC(t,S_t) - \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}_t = rC(t,S_t) dt$$

which leads to the Black-Scholes PDE,

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + rS\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2S^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S^2}=rC$$

Comment: Hey, thanks! However, can you clarify where this term go $\sigma S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dW_t $?

Comment: @sc_ams - this term appears in both $dC$ and $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S} dS$; it cancels out.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I currently don't see it! Can you explain it one more time?

Comment: @sc_ams - note $dC(t,S_t) = [\cdot]dt + \sigma S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dW_t $ and $\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}_t=(\cdot)dt +  \sigma S_t\frac{\partial C}{\partial S}dW_t $. The $dW_t$ terms offset each other if you take the difference.